# Page not found at /polls

Tags: python, django, error-handling, pycharm

I am a total beginner in "django" so I'm following some tutorials currently I' am watching https://youtu.be/JT80XhYJdBw Clever Programmer's tutorial which he follows django tutorial

Everything was cool until making a polls url

Code of views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    HttpResponse("Hello World.You're at the polls index")
```

Code of polls\urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Code of Mypr\urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/',admin.site.urls),
    path('polls/',include('polls.urls')),
]
```

I don't get it I did the same thing but I'm getting error not only polls.In one turtorial he decided to make blog,and again the same error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/
Using the URLconf defined in Mypr.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in 
this order:

admin/
The current path, polls/, didn't match any of these.
```

Please my seniors help me.

Note:I'm using the latest versions of django,windows and as editor I'm using Pycharm.

Already tried(and did not work):

```
from django.urls import path

from polls.views import index

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: Can you put the error log here.

Comment: what's the error ?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error. Feel kinda dumb after figuring out how to solve this.

Your **urls.py** content is all right

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

But it must be included in the `mysite\mysite\urls.py` and not in `mysite\urls.py`.

That means the inner mysite/ directory is the actual Python package for your project. Its name is the Python package name you’ll need to use to import anything inside it.

Answer (score 0):

try to access `polls/` URL in your browser then you will access the page
Because you have accessed the URL of your project, you have to go to this URL to access your app

try by changing your code like this

```
from django.urls import path

from polls.views import index

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: You mean      http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls    if you mean this url this does not work also
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/  but http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin   works

Comment: you registered your polls app in seetings,py

Answer (score -1):

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/
Using the URLconf defined in Mypr.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, polls/, didn't match any of these.
```

You're seeing this error because you have `DEBUG = True` in your Django settings file.
Change that to `False`, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: I can open admin/login but can't polls or blog when I try

Comment: You should edit your question to add informations

Comment: @Timus you mean settings.py from my Mypr package if you mean that even though I did it nothing changed

Comment: I didn't answer, I've just edited your answer a bit (you can see that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65125413/timeline)).